# Docker - Restore installed libraries after exit

Tags: node.js, docker, containers

I am new to docker and I ran these two commands in my mac terminal

```
docker pull amazonlinux
docker run -v $(pwd):/lambda-project -it amazonlinux
```

After running these two commands, I entered into the Linux terminal, where I installed Nodejs and few node modules

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.6/install.sh | bash
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm install 6.11.5
npm -v
npm install serverless -global
```

everything worked fine so far, I was able to run **npm -v** and it showed me npm version and also **serverless -v** worked fine.

Then I did **exit** and I came out of the container into my local terminal.

Then I entered into my container again by using below command

```
docker run -v $(pwd):/lambda-project -it amazonlinux
```

This time my installations are gone. **npm -v** gave me the command not found.

My question is that how can I save the state or modules installed into a container and how can I log in again into the container to work further after exiting from the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With each `docker run` command you are starting another new container. You can run the command `docker ps --all`. You will see all containers (including exited ones) and their IDs. You can restart an exited container with the command `docker restart <id>`. The container is now running. With the command `docker attach <id>` you are back in the container. All installed libraries should still be present, but:

The downloaded shell script sets some shell variables. After attaching to the container, you can run the shell script again: `. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh`. Now you can access npm. This shell command prints out what it did and what you should do to keep those changes.

If you want to keep all those changes and use it regularly you can write a `Dockerfile` which builds an image with all those libs  already installed. This official page gets you started in writing Dockerfiles: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/

Comment: I restarted the docker container using its id, and then I entered into docker using this command "docker exec -it 8e3a4dc73286 bash" but still "npm -v" is showing command not found.

Comment: I updated my answer. It should work now. Creating a `Dockerfile` is the better solution, however.

Comment: Thanks, it works now, as per my knowledge, Dockerfile is used to create a new container, how can I run and enter an existing container using Dockerfile? My use case is that I want to create an image and then container using that image and then work in that container again and again.

Comment: A dockerfile is used to create an __image__. With the `-t` option you can set a tag. After that you can create containers from that image as usual.